# Making Asteroids Game in Python-Whats wrong with it?

Tags: python, pygame

here is the source code for asteroids game.
i used this tutorial http://comp4431.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/tut-wk-3-asteroids/
followed everything as closely as i could.
besides some of the missing fetures like fire, what is wrong with it?
it wont display anything but the starmap.
BTW - New to python

```
import pygame, random, math
from pygame.locals import *
from math import *

WINFLAGS=0
SCREENRECT=Rect(0,0,800,600) #screen res
NSTARS=100
NASTEROIDS=10

#colors
BLACK=(0,0,0)
WHITE=(255,255,255)
YELLOW=(255,255,0)
TRANSPARENT=(1,2,3)

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
        clock.tick(30)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    color=YELLOW
    thrust_value=1.0
    turn_speed=5
    max_speed=10.0

    base_image=pygame.Surface((21,11))
    base_image.fill(TRANSPARENT)
    base_image.set_colorkey(TRANSPARENT)
    pointlist=[(0,0),(0,10),(20,5)]
    pygame.draw.polygon(base_image,color,pointlist)

    def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

            self.image=self.base_image.copy()

            self.rect=self.image.get_rect(center=SCREENRECT.center)

            self.vx=0
            self.vy=0
            self.angle=0

    def update(self):
            self.rect.move_ip(self.vx,self.vy)
            self.wrap()

    def wrap(self):
            if (self.rect.center[0]<0):
                    self.rect.move_ip(SCREENRECT.width,0)
            elif (self.rect.center[0]>=SCREENRECT.width):
                    self.rect.move_ip(-SCREENRECT.width,0)
            if (self.rect.center[1]<0):
                    self.rect.move_ip(SCREENRECT.height,0)
            elif (self.rect.center[1]>=SCREENRECT.height):
                    self.rect.move_ip(0,-SCREENRECT.height)

    def thrust(self):
            a=radians(self.angle)
            self.vx+=self.thrust_value*cos(a)
            self.vy+=self.thrust_value*sin(a)

            vel=sqrt(self.vx*self.vx+self.vy*self.vy)
            if (vel>self.max_speed):
                    self.vx=self.vx*self.max_speed/vel
                    self.vy=self.vy*self.max_speed/vel

    def turn(self,direction):
            self.angle+=self.turn_speed*direction
            while (self.angle<0):
                    self.angle+=360
            while (self.angle>=360):
                    self.angle-=360

            self.image=pygame.transform.rotate(self.base_image,-self.angle)
            self.rect=self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def fire(self):
            print 'fire'

class Asteroid(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    color=YELLOW
    min_speed=2
    max_speed=6

    base_image = pygame.Surface((40,50))
    base_image.fill(TRANSPARENT)
    base_image.set_colorkey(TRANSPARENT)
    pointlist=[(10,0),(30,0),(40,15),(35,25),(20,50),(5,50),(0,25)]
    pygame.draw.polygon(base_image,color,pointlist)

    def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

            self.image=self.base_image.copy()

            x=int(SCREENRECT.width*random.random())
            y=int(SCREENRECT.height*random.random())
            self.rect=self.image.get_rect(center=(x,y))

            velocity=random.randint(self.min_speed, self.max_speed)
            angle=2.0*pi*random.random()#radians
            self.vx=cos(angle)*velocity
            self.vy=sin(angle)*velocity

    def update(self):
            self.rect.move_ip(self.vx,self.vy)
            self.wrap()

    def wrap(self):
            if (self.rect.center[0]<0):
                    self.rect.move_ip(SCREENRECT.width,0)
            elif (self.rect.center[0]>=SCREENRECT.width):
                    self.rect.move_ip(-SCREENRECT.width,0)
            if (self.rect.center[1]<0):
                    self.rect.move_ip(0,SCREENRECT.height)
            elif (self.rect.center[1]>=SCREENRECT.height):
                    self.rect.move_ip(0,-SCREENRECT.height)

def main():
    #init python
    pygame.init()

    #create window
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENRECT.size,WINFLAGS)

    #starmap
    background=pygame.Surface(SCREENRECT.size)
    background.fill(BLACK)
    for i in range(0,NSTARS):
            x=random.randint(0,SCREENRECT.width-1)
            y=random.randint(0,SCREENRECT.height-1)
            pygame.draw.circle(background,WHITE,(x,y),0)

    #blit to screen
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    pygame.display.update()

    player=Player()

    render=pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()
    render.add(player)

    asteroids=pygame.sprite.Group()
    for i in range(0,NASTEROIDS):
            asteroid=Asteroid()
            render.add(asteroid)
            asteroids.add(asteroid)

    while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == QUIT or \
                    (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                      return
            keystate=pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if (keystate[K_UP]):
                    player.thrust()
            direction=keystate[K_RIGHT]-keystate[K_LEFT]
            if (direction !=0):
                    player.turn(direction)
            if (keystate[K_SPACE]):
                    player.fire()
            for asteroid in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,asteroids,False):
                    asteroid.kill()

    render.update()
    render.clear(screen,background)
    dirty=render.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update(dirty)

#run main()
if __name__=="__main__": main()
```

Comment: If possible, you should edit your code down to only the part that displays the problem (e.g. this code should display XYZ on the screen but does not. Here is a code example that does that and nothing else.)

Comment: This is not a good use of this site. You can ask something like "I am having trouble with X" and provide an example of your approach, but dumping your whole project here and asking for troubleshooting ain't gonna get you far.

Answer (score 3):

These statements to update the display should be inside the main loop, instead of after it.

```
render.update()
render.clear(screen,background)
dirty=render.draw(screen)
pygame.display.update(dirty)
```

also, I'm surprised your program does anything given this infinite loop near the beginning

```
while True:
    clock.tick(30)
```